# How to install ExecuteTime extension of Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I installed Jupiter Notebook extensions according to https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html but the ExecuteTime one isn't working. It shows the message **'This nbextension is disabled in the notebook json config, but doesn't provide a yaml file to tell us how to configure it. You can still enable or disable it from here, though'**. However, the folder ***execute_time*** in ***nbextensions*** contains file **ExecuteTime.yaml**. I am on MacOS.

Uninstall/reinstall doesn't help. I have looked for the answer across a lot of threads but there is no solution to this.

Does someone have a clue to that problem? [image: Screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should enable the execution time. For this:

1. pip install jupyterlab_execute_time
2. Then, reload the jupyterlab page.
3. Finally, go to the notebook section in jupyterlab advanced settings and paste:

{"recordTiming" : true,}

If it didn’t work visit: https://github.com/deshaw/jupyterlab-execute-time/tree/master/jupyterlab_execute_time

Comment: Thank you! There is still a message about yaml file but the extension works now. I edited the json file at user/env/etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.d/jupyter_nbextensions_configurator.json (MacOS): 
_{
  "NotebookApp": {
    "nbserver_extensions": {
      "jupyter_nbextensions_configurator": true,
      "recordTiming": true
    }
  }
}_